# Validation required for session attributes in java web project

Tags: java, validation, rest, session

I have the following code line

```
httpSession.setAttribute(CREDENTIALS_ATTRIBUTE, credentials);
```

I have scanned my code using IBM AppScan Source edition and it is showing me an suspect issue of type "Validation.Required" on the above code line.

What type of validations are required while setting some java object to the session attribute on session.

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: Validate the length of `credentials`.  Surely it can’t be larger than, say, one megabyte, right?  If it is, throw an exception and/or return HTTP 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

As said in the manual, the issue is to insist a validation to be done before putting into the httpsession. It can be basic data type validation like number, string, characters using regular expression or your business validations. 
It is mainly to prevent security related threats, because user can inject any junk data which may creep into your HTTP session if proper validation is not done.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply.I have gone though this doc. Still the type of validation i used doesn't work for me.

Comment: Even Session.getAttribute() is also pointing towards the validation.Required issue. What kind of validation there can be for this java object setting or getting to the session??

Comment: setting can be valid (in terms of logical and business) value to the attribute. getting attribute value will sink/set to a variable whatever the value from session copied to variable it might be null or any junk character. Basically you need to decide the potential threat because all that is reported are not potential threat.